# insert data into ms access, using asp

Tags: asp-classic

im trying to insert a new row with new data to an ms access table, using asp page.
i have no background in asp, im an android developer, but those are my client specifications.
i know im doing something very wrong, but i dont know what...
can you please help me?
this is what i was trying to do:

```vb
<% 
'define variables
dim conn, strsql, strMDBPath

Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'Connect to the database
strMDBpath = Server.MapPath("data.mdb")
conn.open "PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" & strMDBPath

'On Error Resume Next

'write to the database
strSql = "INSERT INTO avi (id,first,last) VALUES ("4", '" yom "','" cobi "')"



conn.Execute(strSql)

'close database
conn.close
Set conn = nothing
%>
```

Comment: Please look at one of the existing answers before posting a new question. See: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=classic+asp+add+record

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some ampersands.

```
strSql = "INSERT INTO avi (id,first,last) VALUES (4, '" & yom & "', '" & cobi & "')"
```

Comment: If you where using a Parametrised Query this wouldn't be an issue. Look at using the `ADODB.Command` object over the `ADODB.Connection` object directly.